# Blazor stacked validation attributes error

Tags: validation, attributes, blazor, .net-7.0

I have a model which needs to be validated and I want to do that using the ValidationAttribute. This is a property of my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start is mandatory")]
[Time(ErrorMessage = "Format: mm:ss.fff")]
[TimeRange(ErrorMessage = "Start not after end")]
public string StartProxy { get; set; }
```

'Required' of course is an existing validator, but the Time and TimeRange validators are both custom and created by me. So whenever I leave the inputfield empty, the required validator is returning a failed validationresult and both the Time and TimeRange validators are not called. But when I enter something that is not a time, the Time validator is returning a failed validation result (`return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });`) and the TimeRange validator is still called???? That results in an exception because the TimeRange validator expects a valid time-string.

So my question is, how can I achieve this 'stacked' validators pattern and how should I implement my validator correctly.

Thanks in advance,

Herman

Comment: [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) and [Blazored FluentValidation](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) are the best way to do custom and complex validation.

Comment: Hi @Lex, thanks for you comment. Sorry I reply a little bit later, but I'm working on a kind of hobbyproject, so not checking this every day. At the end I have now implemented your suggested validation which works perfectly. Thanks